# Same piece of code, different behavior on Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, windows, linux

I know the following piece of code is not right since I'm assigning an value to an arbitrary address.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int *i;
*i = 12;     // Not right.... i is not initialized.
cout << *i << endl;
return 0;
}
```

This piece of code gives a segmentation fault on Linux. However, on Windows it outputs 12...

Why would it work on Windows? Am I not assigning 12 to some arbitrary location my program has no privilege over?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.  Anything can happen.

Comment: The behaviour is not actually different, but the same: undefined.

Comment: If you do this... You'd better hope that you try to access something invalid so that Linux will kill it. You never know when you might accidentally uncover a bug and write over something important (more common in Windows, most of these bugs are ironed out in Linux).

Comment: It also really depends on how the pointer is initialized. On Linux, maybe the pointer is initialized to `NULL`, which is never valid. Maybe Windows makes it the beginning of the stack frame, random junk, etc.

Comment: A page I wrote a while back on this topic: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/checking-early.html .  It uses fortran as an example, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 12):

It actually invokes undefined behavior. So both behaviors are correct, i.e it may give segfault, or it may not.

On the next run, the Windows version may crash, and the Linux version may send you threatening mails!

In other words, anything can happen. Neither the C++ specification, nor the (standard-conformant) compilers give any guarantee, which is why the C++ specification refers to such behavior as *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

Because the random data which *happens to be* in the place where `i` is put on the stack *happens* to form a non-writable address under Linux, but *happens* to contain a writable address on Windows.

However note that you cannot know for sure what other effects the code has on Windows. It *could* be that if you happen to start the program on Friday the 13th at 6:16pm then the address *happens* to be the one where the system call number for "output" is stored, and it may *happen* to be that `12` is the call for "delete file", and it may *happen* that this deletes the most important file you have. Yes, it's extremely unlikely, but not at all impossible (it might only happen, if you compile it with a specific version of a specific compiler using specific compiler settings).

Or in short, nobody can tell you for sure what happens when you run this code (note that even under Linux, the behaviour may be different if you change compiler options, compiler version or just happen to call it with command line arguments ...)

Answer (score 1):

@Nawaz and @celtschk are right.  Your code does invoke undefined behavior, so both behaviors are correct.  Still, there is a reason you are seeing this particular undefined behavior.  The reason is worth understanding.

When the operating system loads the program at run-time, it opens for it a *virtual address space.*  On a 64-bit system, the virtual space extends from address zero through address 0xffffffffffffffff.

Your system naturally has only a tiny fraction of the actual, physical memory it would need to fill such a vast address space.  Moreover, your system must share the memory it does have between the several, distinct processes that may be running at once -- each of which processes has its own, private virtual address space.

So here is what the system does.  It initially assigns your newly loaded program a small block of memory -- probably 4 kiB -- and maps this to a small segment of the address space, as 0xfffffffffffff000 through 0xffffffffffffffff.  Your program builds a *stack* of stored data objects in this space.  If the stack grows past the 4 kiB, the system will assign another 4 kiB, as 0xffffffffffffe000 through 0xffffffffffffefff, and will do it in a manner that is transparent to the running program.

So long as the program builds and uses its stack in an orderly, prescribed manner, it runs as though it were unaware of any limitation on the size of its stack.  However, should the program access memory in a disorderly manner, which yours does, then the result depends on several factors, but will surely raise a system exception if the access is to an address for which the system has never assigned the program actual memory to use.

Now, this answer leaves out a lot of details.  There is a second kind of memory of which you may be aware, a *heap* or *dynamic memory pool.*  There are other factors, too, including "disk swapping."  However, if the pointer `i` happens to point into memory the program is already using for some purpose or other, no system exception will be raised.  Does it point into such memory?  Hard to say.  Plainly, in your case, it seems to do so on one system but not on the other.

By the way, I would differ slightly from @celtschk on one, small point.  Modern CPUs and operating systems are specifically constructed to prevent systems disasters like the one of which he speaks.  The *C and C++ standards* do not guarantee that such disasters will not occur, but the operating systems do, unless the program is run with superuser privileges (and even then there may exist partially effective safeguards).  I don't think that you have to worry much about inadvertently wiping your disk with a normal, usermode program.  Still, on an embedded system, it is another matter, and there @celtschk is quite right.

Comment: I'm using mingw of gcc4.7 on windows 7 64bit. But it compiles 32bit code.
Would using a different compiler change the behavior? Like how i points into the memory the program is already using.

Comment: Right.  Using a different compiler, or different settings on the same compiler, or the same compiler on a different CPU architecture, could indeed change the behavior.  Normally, a programmer does not care which memory is used to store an object.  He only cares that storage exists.  Therefore, even though C++ affords excellent access to hardware primitives, the compiler normally chooses addresses without asking the programmer's advice.  One compiler will choose different addresses for objects in the same code than another will, which accounts for the difference in behavior for code like yours.